# How to parse mif file?

Tags: java, parsing, gis

Can someone give an advice how to parse data of .mif file?

```
REGION 1
5
-3010.162251 24759.203912
-3013.594507 24746.897137
-3000.110586 24742.400469
-2996.511292 24755.084298
-3010.162251 24759.203912
BRUSH(1,0)
REGION 1
7
3102.893 -1432.264
3198.267205 -1508.743575
3219.752759 -1481.67002
3140.143659 -1415.623655
3134.753948 -1411.037831
3126.016 -1408.663
3102.893 -1432.264
BRUSH(1,0)
```

File have this structure. For every type (Region, Pline, etc) there are optional parameters(Brush in example). How can I check If the object has  these parameters or not?
Do I need to try to parse the file into a logical block?

Comment: As I can see every region starts with REGION <number>. Аs a consequence every region ends with REGION <number>, so you you can just read whole region as a raw strings, remove coordinates and analyze what's left.

Comment: Read a line.  If it starts with "BRUSH" then you should modify the region object you’re currently parsing.  If it starts with "REGION" (or "PLINE" etc.) then your current region (if there is one) is done, and you should prepare a new region object.

Answer (score 0):

I can see many ways to parse It. Everything depends on how fast you want It to be, how big the file is going to be and how this parsing is going to be mapped in memory (the respective entity).

I think using regex is the easiest way to create parsing rules, despite not being the faster one.
I would read line by line, then:

- Check a new beginning of region by using the expression REGION [0-9]+
- (Any times this) Check coordinates patterns by -?\d*.\d+|\d+.\d*$ -?\d*.\d+|\d+.\d*$
- After any number of occurrences of the previous check, gather the information present within this line. You can make a lot validations here to make sure you are getting only desired info here.

Tutorial about regex in Java: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html